# jprofiler failed to connect remote red5 server

Tags: linux, red5, jprofiler

all , in my linux remote server, I installed jprofiler successfully, and I add

> JPROFILER_HOME=/opt/jprofiler9/bin/linux-x64 export
> LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$JPROFILER_HOME

in my /etc/profile, and in my red5 startup file red5.sh
I add

> -agentlib:jprofilerti=port=8849
> -Xbootclasspath/a:/opt/jprofiler9/bin/agent.jar

in export JAVA_OPTS, which became:

> export JAVA_OPTS="$LOGGING_OPTS $SECURITY_OPTS $JAVA_OPTS $JVM_OPTS
> $JYTHON -agentlib:jprofilerti=port=8849
> -Xbootclasspath/a:/opt/jprofiler9/bin/agent.jar"

however when I use jprofiler client to try to connect it, it failed.

in server start log,
it blocked at here:

> JProfiler Using JVMTI
>
> JProfiler JVMTI version 1.1 detected.
>
> JProfiler 64-bit library
>
> JProfiler Listening on port: 8849.
>
> JProfiler Instrumenting native methods.
>
> JProfiler Can retransform classes.
>
> JProfiler Can retransform any class.
>
> JProfiler Native library initialized
>
> JProfiler VM initialized
>
> JProfiler Waiting for a connection from the JProfiler GUI ...
>
> JProfiler Listening on port: 8849.

And in my client, nothing can be watched... I guess it not connected success

Then I add ",nowait" after -agentlib:jprofilerti=port=8849

It did not stock this time ,and red5 server start success. but when I tried to connect the jprofiler, it failed again! and this time, it show me message in client that it failed...

Hope someone can help me , THKS!

Comment: The log file output is OK. It sounds like you cannot open a network connection. Are the host name and the port in the remote session correct? Do you have a firewall in between?

Comment: Yes, I made a packet capture and found the result is that my company has blocked it! （=。=） ， and I used agent and everthing is OK， Thanks anyway!